# Trouble with such u-substitution that $du=e^{-2\pi i f(t)}f'(t)dt$ for $I=\int_0^1e^{-2\pi i f(t)}dt$ and integration by parts

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, substitution

**Update:** After depressingly many hours I realized that the task of bounding the integral is quite simple and in all likelihood, there is no such $u$-substitution conundrum as I have discussed here (you just perform integration by parts to the expression $\frac{-2\pi i f'(t)e^{-2\pi i f(t)}}{-2\pi i f'(t)}$). It is more likely that the combination of a different-ish way of writing mathematics + the conciseness of the author made me misinterpret the exact steps the author had in mind. I will, however, leave this question open because I have discussed here is still not clear to me: If you would perform the $u$-substitution, in what if in any way could you "move forward" with the integrand $\frac{1}{f'(u^{-1}(u))}$.

Let $f\in C^2([0,1])$ such that $|f'| > r$ for some $r > 0$ on $[0,1]$ and consider the integral

$$I = \int_0^1 e^{-2\pi i f(t)}dt$$

A proof I am reading wants to bound $|I|$ by performing such u-substitution that $du = e^{-2\pi i f(t)}f'(t)dt$ and integrating by parts to the function $\frac{1}{f'(t)}$. The proof does not give any details beyond the closing remarks on the tasked bound, so I am trying to replicate the entire process.

So what I have figured so was is that since $f'$ is outside some neighborhood of zero throughout $[0,1]$, we can safely write

$$I = \int_0^1\frac{-2\pi if'(t)}{-2\pi if'(t)}e^{-2\pi i f(t)}dt$$

The given $du$ suggest that

$$u(t) := \frac{e^{-2\pi i f(t)}}{-2\pi i}$$

so that

$$I = \int_{u(0)}^{u(1)}\frac{-2\pi i}{f'(t)}du$$

(there's likely a slight caveat here regarding integration over complex domain, which I am not sure about but will postpone to a later question).

**Troubling part:** At this point I am unfortunately a bit lost regarding two things:

What should the argument of $f'$ be after the $u$-substitution? 100% of the times I have had to use any substitution have been such that *everything works out nicely in the end*. Since after the substitution we are integrating over $u$'s image of $[0,1]$, wouldn't we have something like $f'(u^{-1}(u))$ instead of $f'(t)$ in $I$. That is,

$$I = \int_{u(0)}^{u(1)}\frac{-2\pi i}{f'(u^{-1}(u))}du$$

assuming that $u$ is invertible. And if so, how would you precisely do the integration by parts on the integral $I$? I get that you would integrate the constant function $1$ to be the monomial $u$, but my brain just shuts down when I try to work with $\frac{1}{f'(u^{-1}(u))}$ w.r.t. $u$.

Comment: Are you just trying to justify $|I|\leq 1$? It's just $\left|\int_a^bg(t)\,dt\right|\leq |b-a|M$, where $M$ is a bound on the magnitude of the integrand ($|g|\leq M$). In this case, assuming $f$ is real, we know $|e^{2\pi i f(t)}| = 1$, so you have $|I| \leq |1-0|\cdot 1 = 1$. Is that what you need?

Comment: @MPW No, the precise upper bound of the proof is a bit more involved, but the details are not important to this u-substitution specific question. What I am trying to do is to understand how I should perform the integration by parts after the u-substitution. In particular, I am a bit lost on $f$'s argument after the sub.